# Why am I getting an invalid initializer error?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, implicit-conversion

I'm relatively new to **C** and I'm trying to write a simple code that checks if a year is a leap year or not.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int year;
    printf("%s","Please enter a year: ");
    scanf("%d",&year);
    char leapYear[] = ((year % 4) == 0) ? ((year / 100 % 4)==0 ? "y": "n"):"n" ;
    printf("%s", leapYear);

}
```

I'm getting an invalid initializer error and I don't know why.

Comment: An initializer must be a constant expression that is evaluated at compile time. Yours is not a constant expression. Use: `char leapYear[2]; leapYear= ...`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: No, it does not need to be a constant expression. Initializers for objects with static or thread storage duration need to be constant expressions or string literals (C 2018 6.7.9 4). `leapYear` has automatic storage duration. And `char leapYear[2]; leapYear= ...` would not work because arrays are not assignable.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, good answer from Vlad! Didn't Catch that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this expression

```
((year % 4) == 0) ? ((year / 100 % 4)==0 ? "y": "n"):"n"
```

the string literals are converted to pointers to their first elements and you nay not initialize an array of characters with pointers.

To make it more clear consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char s1[] = "y";
    char s2[] = "y" + 0;
}
```

The first array declaration

```
    char s1[] = "y";
```

will successfully compile. There is used a string literal to initialize the array.

The second array declaration

```
    char s2[] = "y" + 0;
```

will not compile because in expressions string literals are converted (with rare excaptions) to pointers to their first elements.

Use instead the following approach

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int year;
    printf("%s","Please enter a year: ");
    scanf("%d",&year);
    char leapYear[2];
    strcpy( leapYear, ( (year % 4 ) == 0) ? ((year / 100 % 4)==0 ? "y": "n"):"n" );
    printf("%s", leapYear);
}
```

And as  **Paul Ogilvie** wrote in a comment instead of an array you could define a pointer like

```
const char *leapYear = ((year % 4) == 0) ? ((year / 100 % 4)==0 ? "y": "n"):"n" ;
```

Comment: Or `char *leapYear = ...`?

Comment: _"because in expressions string literals are converted to pointers to their first element"_ That's the definitive answer! Great!

Comment: Excellent answer. I knew it didn't work 'this' way but I didn't know why. Now I know why.

Answer (score 0):

If the size not stated, the compiler evaluates the size of a c-string from the assigned const string expression which is not present in your code (the value of the string `leapYear` depends on the given condition).

So, you have to preset the size of the array if you want to provide condtions within a single line:

```
char leapYear[2];
leapYear[0] = ((year % 4) == 0) ? ((year / 100 % 4) == 0 ? 'y' : 'n') : 'n' ;
leapYear[1] = '\0'; // so that you don't get garbage in your terminal
```

**EDIT**:

I forgot about `strcpy()` so here it is (thanks to @Vlad):

```
char leapYear[2];
strcpy(leapYear, ((year % 4 ) == 0) ? ((year / 100 % 4) == 0 ? "y" : "n") : "n");
```